# Name of Author does not appear in Beamer footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am making my first `beamer`-presentation, and for some reason, the author name will not appear in the footline. The title name and the name of the institution do appear, but not the author.

Here the example, sorry if it's long, but I really don't know where the error is...

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif]{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage {linguex}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage {xyling}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{phonetic}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}


\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
\beamertemplateballitem


\title{ZZZZZ}
\subtitle{QQQQ}
\author{XXXX}
\institute{YYYY}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}



\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please provide the part inside `document`-group.

Comment: I am sorry, do you mean after \begin{document}? I though the error would be in the preamble somewhere... Should I include the whole document, basically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "for some reason" is, that the theme you choose, does not display the author in the footline, so either choose another theme or redefine the footline.

---

Offtopic: but both `slidestop`, and `mathserif` are deprecated and should be replaced by `t` and  `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`, respectively.

```
\documentclass[t,compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%
            \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
        leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
        \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
        \hfill%
        \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
        \hfill%
        {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\title{ZZZZZ}
\subtitle{QQQQ}
\author{XXXX}
\institute{YYYY}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        abc
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]